# Form action link goes to home page

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, submit

I'm trying to make a submit button link to one of my existing pages.

After clicking the button, my browser goes straight to localhost:8080/c2c/ instead of my target localhost:8080/c2c/?page_id=20

```
    <form action='http://localhost:8080/c2c/?page_id=20'>
        <input type="submit" value="New Buy Order" id="buySubmit"></input>
    </form>
```

My guess is because of my local server it isn't going to go to the link correctly. Just not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:8080/c2c/` IS the target of your form, so it's doing exactly what you're telling it to. You need to create a file inside the `c2c` directory, name it `index.php` and put the following code in `index.php` to see the `page_id`

```
<?php
echo (int) $_GET['page_id'];
```

Edit: of course this code is overly simplified, but it will show you what's happening...

---

Edit 2: revised code.
This is really how you should be doing it. Using `method="get"` in your form will show the query parameters in the URL string, as in your original form.

**form.html**

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/c2c/index.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="20">
    <input type="submit" value="New Buy Order" id="buySubmit"></input>
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo (int) $_GET['page_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Added the echo statement above. Same result. EDIT: It gives an error of undefined page index.